# Spark Streaming - Read a file from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I want to read a file from the file-metadata that I send as a kafka message. Kafka message contains details such as complete filename as saved in hdfs. I want my spark-streaming application to read the metadata of file, and read the file to apply some logic on it.

I could have used FileStreamSource but it keeps a watch on a single directory. However, in my case, the directory may change. Can you please suggest me any workaround?

----- KAFKA CODE --------

```py
import json
import requests
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from json import dumps
from time import sleep
import os

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],value_serializer=lambda x:dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
for e in range(1000):
    response=requests.get('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/testing/history').text
    file_name='response_'+str(e)+'.txt'
    with open(file_name,'w') as file:
       file.write(response)

    string=json.dumps({"filename":"hdfs://localhost:9000/covid/"+file_name})
    os.system('hdfs dfs -put '+file_name+' /covid')
    print(string)
    producer.send('load_json_topic',value=string)
    sleep(3)
```

--------- SPARK CODE------------

```py
import requests
import json
import os
from pyspark.sql.functions import split,explode
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class DataCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataframe=None
        self.status=None
        self.datacount=None
        self.lastupdated=None
        config=SparkConf().setAppName("COVID").setMaster("local[*]")
        self.sc=SparkContext(conf=config)
        self.ssc=StreamingContext(self.sc,1)

    def data_collection(self):
        zkQuorum="localhost:2181"
        topic="load_json_topic"
        kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(self.ssc, [topic],{"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"})
        lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
        response=lines.map(lambda x:json.loads(x))
        spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("COVID").getOrCreate()

        try:
            filename=response.map(lambda x:json.loads(x)['filename'])
            response=spark.read.json(filename)
            response.pprint()

        except Exception as e:
            response.pprint()
            print("***********************Exception occured******************************",e)
        self.ssc.start()
        self.ssc.awaitTermination()
        print("Data Collected")
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data ?

Comment: Kafka Message : {"filename": "hdfs://localhost:9000/covid/response_1.txt"}

Comment: what code have you tried ? @KUSUMAKARSHUKLA